# Does JavaScript have the equivalent of Python's __getattribute__?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, v8

Does JavaScript have the equivalent of Python's `__getattribute__`? In the sense that I'd like an object, `a`, for which a reference to a property `x` is equivalent to `a.__get__('x')`. Trying to get this to work in V8. Possible?

Example: an object which makes REST-ful calls:

```
RESTful("some-url").foo({x:1}) => response of call to "some-url/foo?x=1"
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want to accomplish?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Catch access to undefined property in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2756431/catch-access-to-undefined-property-in-javascript) and [Is there an equivalent of the __noSuchMethod__ feature for properties, or a way to implement it in JS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266789/is-there-an-equivalent-of-the-nosuchmethod-feature-for-properties-or-a-way-t)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible for properties, though there is a non-standard way ([`__noSuchMethod__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/noSuchMethod)) for methods which is only available for Firefox.

Comment: [ES-Harmony Proxies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266789/is-there-an-equivalent-of-the-nosuchmethod-feature-for-properties-or-a-way-t/3757676#3757676) to the rescue :)