# Is there Object.watch for all properties / a shim for __noSuchMethod__ available?

Tags: javascript, object, local-storage, getter-setter, nosuchmethod

I would like to extend `localStorage` by executing some code each time a setting is fetched/stored. I could define a getter/setter for all existing properties of `localStorage`, but the problem lies in new settings.

For example, `localStorage['somenewsetting'] = 123` creates a new setting. I would like to automatically define a getter/setter for this property so that my addition code is also executed for new settings.

Basically I need `Object.watch`, but for all properties. What I found was [`__noSuchMethod__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/noSuchMethod), but it is not available on Chrome. Is there any shim available for this method? Or is there another way of watching *all* properties of an object?

Again, I need to make this work on Chrome.

Comment: How about accessing all assignments using `setItem`.  I wrote a wrapper/façade class for `localStorage`/`sessionStorage` to serialize `RegExp`s and even strings (as quoted strings) and to deserialize plain objects, `Date`s, and `RegExp`s.  You could do the same with the intent of adding your additional code inside the `setItem` proxy function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, at least, not for Chrome.  `__noSuchMethod__` only works for functions, anyway.

`Proxy` support is [under discussion](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3aproxies) for the next version of ECMAScript (Harmony), and even [already implemented in SpiderMonkey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy).  Until then, you're out of luck, I'm afraid.

— there was [a request to implement `__noSuchMethod__` in V8](https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=264) but it was refused. Requests to implement Proxy haven't been any more successful: [633 was merged as duplicate](http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=633), and the Chromium team [doesn't care much about implementing Proxy support](https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=1543).

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, I want that too.  So do many, many other people.  Isn't going to happen.  Ever.  Chrome (V8) follows webkit in terms of its JS API.  `__noSuchMethod__` is a non-standard event created by Mozilla and has been officially rejected from ECMAScript (JavaScript).

In other words, it will never exist :'(

(or if it does, it will be after much arguing and it won't be any time soon)

Comment: Nope, you can't work around it as it's far too low-level.  Well you can patch chrome (there's a patch if you look for it), but that's only really helpful for you, not development in general :)